# Call Controller Method Which Return View With Ajax Call From Asp.net View Page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, routes

I have button. I want to route new view when i clicked the button. The button is like below:

```
<button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-warning" style="height:35px;width:120px"> <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> <translate>Search</translate> </button>
```

when button is clicked and than the method which is below run:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("test", "ControllerName")',
            data: { Name: $('#Name').val() },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
```

my controller action is  below:

```
   public ActionResult test(string CityName) {
            ViewBag.CityName = CityName;
            return View();
                          }
```

when i debug my program, flow came to my controller action. But index web page don't route to the test view page. Error is not occurred. What can i do for this state ?

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect in the POST method then dont use ajax. Alternatively if you what to add the view you return in the `test()` method, then handle the `success` callback and update the DOM (although in that case `ViewBag.CityName = CityName;` is pointless) - e.g. `success: function(response) { $(someElement).html(response); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you wants to refresh page:**

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();
}

public ViewResult Test()
{
    ViewBag.Name = Request["txtName"];
    return View();
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post ))
{
    <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-warning" style="height:35px;width:120px" value="Search"/> 
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
}
```

**Test.cshtml:**

```
@ViewBag.Name
```

=============================================

**If you don't wants to refresh page:**

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult TestAjax(string Name)
{
    ViewBag.Name = Name;
    return PartialView();
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-warning" style="height:35px;width:120px" value="Search"/> 
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />


<script>
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestAjax", "Home")',
        data: { Name: $("#txtName").val() },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divContent").html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**TestAjax.cshtml:**

```
@ViewBag.Name
```

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling with that last row, getting the data into the table, so simple and straight forward, gr8 answer <3