# The view doesn't return from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to carry data by onclick function to the next page. All data is carried along with by giving parameter but it doesn't return View from the controller. Please help me. I'm stuck in here two days this is my school project.

OnClick button:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <button class='btn bg-blue next' onclick="checkamt(@Model.TotalAmt)">Next</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ComfirmPay(int e = 0, string TaxType = null, int CurrentAmt = 0)
{
    ViewBag.TotalAmt = e;
    ViewBag.CurrentAmt = CurrentAmt;            
    ViewBag.TaxType = TaxType;            

    return View("ComfirmPay");
}
```

Ajax:

```
function checkamt(e) {
   var amount = @ViewBag.CurrentAmt;

   if (amount < e) {
       alert('bad');
       window.location.href = 'http://localhost:22822/Home/PayTax';
   }
   else {
       alert('good');
       $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("ComfirmPay", "Home")',
                data: { e: e, taxtype: taxtype, currentamt: currentamt },
                beforeSend: function () {
              },
              success: function () {
              },
              complete: function () {                      
              }
          }) 
        }  
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9">
    <p class="text-muted">You have total <b class="text-green">@ViewBag.CurrentAmt</b> points</p>
</div>
```

Comment: add error section in your ajax call and check what error it returning.

Comment: return view not work when you use ajax.

Comment: How to fix it Sir?

Comment: you can use returnPartialView();

Comment: You are using any 'Method' in your `action ComfirmPay` like `get` or `post`?

Comment: No, I dont use any method in action ComfirmPay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ajax function and do this

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ComfirmPay", "Home")" + "?e=" + e + "&taxtype=" + taxtype + "&currentamt=" + currentamt
```

The comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39523270/6763163) post explains a little more about why what you are trying to do does not work.

Answer (score 0):

i think for your purpose there is no need of ajax call. you can use `window.location.href`as follows

```
 function checkamt(e) {
   var amount = @ViewBag.CurrentAmt;
   if (amount < e) {
         window.location.href = 'http://localhost:22822/Home/PayTax';
   }
  else {
        window.location.href = '/Home/ComfirmPay?e='+e+'&taxtype='+taxtype+'&currentamt='+currentamt;
   }  
 }
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult ComfirmPay(string e, string TaxType, string CurrentAmt)
{
  ViewBag.TotalAmt = e;
  ViewBag.CurrentAmt = CurrentAmt;            
  ViewBag.TaxType = TaxType;            
  return View();
}
```