# Calling controller from view

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017

so i'm  quite new to MVC,
how can i call a method that i made in a controller and how can i pass data to it from the view? or how does this work?

i have a controller method that requires an object which i have a list of them in the view, called item

how can i pass that item to my kosarba method?

regular c# would be `kosarba(item);`
but how is it here? 
here's the code.

```
  string shopid = "";
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult kosarba([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Price,Men,Akcios,Akcioszazalek")]Parfum parfum) {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (shopid == "") {
                    shopid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                }
                ShoppingCart kosarcucc = new ShoppingCart();
                kosarcucc.itemID = parfum.Id;
                kosarcucc.instanceID = shopid;
                if (parfum.Akcios)
                {
                    double szam = parfum.Price;
                    double akciosar = Math.Floor((100 - parfum.Akcioszazalek) * szam / 100);
                    kosarcucc.osszeg = Math.Floor(akciosar);
                }
                else {
                    kosarcucc.osszeg = parfum.Price;
                }
                db.ShoppingCart.Add(kosarcucc);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(shopid);
        }
```

thanks

Comment: By ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523270/call-controller-method-which-return-view-with-ajax-call-from-asp-net-view-page

Comment: @ZavenZareyan i figured if i click a submit button, the httppost method would be called, but how can i specify the values it gets? without forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your data (item) should be stored in the model. Your view should update the model and the controller should retrieve the data from there.

For reference see the tutorial on MVC pattern in ASP.Net CORE
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: it's in the database, there is already a get; set; for everything.
my question was how can i  instantiate my method in the view