# return view in action method with ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to return a view in action (called Ajax) but it is possible that I will return Jason but if I return the view, it will not go to the view because the action was called with ajax.

action:

```
        [Route("/RecoveryPassword")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RecoveryPassword(string email)
        {
             var user=//something;
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Json(new { userNull =true});
            }

            if (user.IsActive == false)
            {
                return view("ViewName",ModelName));
            }

        }
```

ajax code:

```
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "Post",
                       dataType: "Json",
                       url: "/RecoveryPassword",
                       data: { "email": 'test@gmail.com'},
                       success: function (result) {
                           if (result.userNull  == true) {
                              alert('hello');
                           }
                       },
                   });
```

What do you think I can do?
Thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Controller Method Which Return View With Ajax Call From Asp.net View Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523270/call-controller-method-which-return-view-with-ajax-call-from-asp-net-view-page)

Comment: I would try to steer clear of mixing the returned content of actions like this, stick to either a view or JSON but do not mix.

Comment: instead of returning view, return the URL of that action  and use `window.location=result.url`

Answer (score 2):

You can't render a view from AJAX.
What you can do is use `window.location.href= '@Url.Action(ViewName, controllerName)'` or if you don't use AJAX then you can simply return the View from your controller action.

Comment: In that case, how do I pass the model?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

using ajax you can only return a partial view or a view as a partial

```
        [HttpPost("/RecoveryPassword")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RecoveryPassword(string email)
        {
             var user=//something;
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Json(new { userNull =true});
            }

            if (user.IsActive == false)
            {
                return PartialView("ViewName",ModelName));
            }

        }
```

create a div in your view where you are going to put your returned view

```
<div id="partialView">
        <partial name=""ViewName" model="ModelName" />
</div>
```

and ajax

```
 success: function (result) {
            $("#partialView").html(result);
    },
```