# Received NULL Object in Controller when send request from view ( Ajax) even I use [FromBody] C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Model:

```
public class From
        {
            public DateTime from { get; set; }
            public DateTime to { get; set; }

        }
```

Controller:

```
public MediaViewModel DashboardMediaByDate([FromBody] From y)
        { // some logic }
```

View:

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        // Get value on button click and show alert
        $("#myBtn").click(function () {
            var from =  {
                from: $("#from").val(), to: $("#to").val()
            };
            alert(from.from);
            var y = JSON.stringify(from);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: y,
                dataType: 'json',

                url: "/Queues/DashboardMediaByDate",
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).done(function (res) {
                alert(res);
            });
        });

    });
   

</script>
```

When I debug the request from browser :

[Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdQDz.png)
[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYXRZ.png)

What I received in Controller:

[Method Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YJGp.png)
How can I send the object to controller from view model ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You don't need to stringify `y` and that may be your whole problem.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately  I received NULL Object ( Still Same Issue )

Comment: Can you also show the request body from the browser dev tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `AJAX` call to get your data as required:

`AJAX`:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Get value on button click and show alert
        $("#myBtn").click(function () {
        
            var from =  {
                from: $("#from").val(), to: $("#to").val()
            };
            
            alert(from.from);
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {'json': JSON.stringify(from)},
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/Queues/DashboardMediaByDate"
            }).done(function (res) {
                alert(res);
            });
        });
    });
   
</script>
```

And your `Controller` method:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DashboardMediaByDate(string json)
{
        MediaViewModel myModel = new MediaViewModel();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

        //Get your variables here from AJAX call
        var from  = Convert.ToDateTime(jsondata["from"]);
        var to  = Convert.ToDateTime(jsondata["to"]);
        
        //Your logic

        return Json(new {myModel=myModel});
}
```

Changes from your original call:

1. Removed `contentType` from your `AJAX` call
2. Added `[HttpPost]` attribute on your `Controller` method
3. Removed `[FromBody]` attribute to get your data as a `JSON` string
4. Changed your `data` to send a `JSON` string instead of a `Model`

Once you get your data as a `JSON` string, you can de-serialize it your `Model` structure as required. I usually use this method when my `Model` does not have many properties.

You are using `AJAX` for your functionality which is generally used to update a portion of the page without reloading the entire page. If you want to redirect in the `POST` method from your `Controller` with a `Model`, then don't use ajax for your purpose. Alternatively if you know what to add to the view you return then handle the success callback and update the DOM.

You can access the above `Model` in your `success` method inside your `AJAX` like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    //Get your model here
    console.log(data.myModel);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained the changes you made. Though, I do not agree that bypassing model binding is a good solution.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for the feedback. I usually use this method when my `Model` does not have many properties and I only need to send small amount of data.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine but I made this changes:


1) `using Nancy.Json;`
 2) `dynamic jsondata = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);`

Comment: Another Question there is any way to Change the value of the `@model MediaViewModel`

Where as you see my function return ( res : type of `MediaViewModel` )

I need to update the data in view with this result 

Kindly advice ?

Comment: @RahulSharma I appreciate your cooperation

Comment: @MohammedAl-Quraan You are using `AJAX` for your functionality which is generally used to update a portion of the page without reloading the entire page. If you want to redirect in the `POST` method  from your `Controller` with a `Model`, then don't use ajax for your purpose. Alternatively if you know what to add the view you return then handle the success callback and update the DOM. You can read more on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523270/call-controller-method-which-return-view-with-ajax-call-from-asp-net-view-page. I am updating my answer on how you can send a `Model`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate you support