# Server Error in '/' Application in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am working with ASP.NET MVC .
I give the proper url name but error is the resource is not found.

I am click the checkout button and trying to open view but view is not open.

Please see below code.

cartDisplay.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "cartDisplay";
}

<h2>Add to Cart Details</h2>

<script src="~/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div style="display: inline">
    <div class="text-left">
        <button class='btn btn-group-sm btn-success' onclick='submit()'>CheckOut</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="example">

    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

        //here other code
      
      function submit() {
            debugger
            $.ajax({
                url: "/User/addToCartOrderStore",           //here I am giving the proper url but error is resource not found error
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

UserController.cs

```cs
//Shipping Details and order details
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult addToCartOrderStore()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addToCartOrderStore(FormCollection sh)
{
    ....
}
```

I am trying to open below view but below view is not open

`addToCartOrderStore.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "addToCartOrderStore";
}

<h2>AddToCart OrderStore</h2>

<script src="~/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<br />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse text-center">
    <div class="container text-center">

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse text-center">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "index")</li>
                <li> @Html.ActionLink("My Cart", "cartdisplay")</li>
                <li> @Html.ActionLink("My Orders", "orderdisplay")</li>*@

                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout")</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form id="form"></form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var today = new Date();

        var maxDate = today.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

        $("#form").kendoForm({

            layout: "grid",
            grid: {
                cols: 2,
                gutter: 20
            },
            items: [
                {
                    type: "group",
                    label: "Customer Address",
                    items: [
                        {
                            field: "firstname",
                            label: "First Name:",
                            validation: { required: true }
                        },
                        {
                            field: "lastname",
                            label: "Last Name:",
                            validation: { required: true }
                        },
```

See below error image:

[image]

I am trying to open view but give an error the resource cannot be found.

I trying to return view but give an error but view is not shown.

need help

Comment: First, put breakpoint on `ViewBag.Title = "addToCartOrderStore";` and check that you hit this breakpoint. If YES, you will know that problem in rendering the `addToCartOrderStore.cshtml` view.

Comment: have a look at question/answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/39523270/493557 very similar to your question. You're making an ajax call to simply redirect. However, if you must do it the way you have, your addToCartOrderStore should return a redirectToUrl value in it's response, not the actual view, so that your page can redirect to the correct url

Comment: @Victor when I debug the code then ```ViewBag.Title = "addToCartOrderStore"```  viewbag.title give the addtocartorderstore but addtocartorderstore is not open can you help more

Comment: @G_P I am still facing this issue i am student sir can you help more please

Comment: @Victor I am still not find the solution can you help why not work I put a debugger but still it give an error ```User/Undefined```

Comment: @Victor ok but this issue is not related regarding kendo error is thrown in mvc it is an mvc error

Comment: @RahulPatil: If you sure that this problem doesn't related to the `kendo` than I would suggest to remove from your code any parts related to the `kendo` and create the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this way more people can reproduce the problem and help you.